# how to count articles in dictionary in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, count, key-value

I am wanting to make a count of items in the dictionary. When a user enters a value to search, it finds the value's key, then returns the next key before it. i.e.({john:fred, fred: bill})

if the user enters john, it will return bill and vice versa.

My code is:

```
myDict = {}
with open("names.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        for pair in line.strip ().split(', '):
            i = 0
            x = 0
            (key, val) = pair.split (":")
            myDict[key.strip(":")] = val
            print "father: ", key , " son: ", val


def findFather (myDict, lookUp):
    father = ""
    for key, val in myDict.iteritems( ):
        if val == lookUp:
            key = key
            father = key
            return father
lookUp = raw_input ("Enter a son's name: ")
print findFather(myDict, lookUp)
```

the dictionary values are:

```
john:fred, fred:bill, sam:tony, jim:william, william:mark, krager:holdyn, danny:brett, danny:issak, danny:jack, blasen:zade, david:dieter, adam:seth, seth:enos
```

Comment: you're doing quite a few unnecessary things in your code... for instance what are those unused `i` and `x`; other than that, what should happen when "sam" is entered?

Comment: Yes, the i and x were supposed to be taken out, my error when uploading this. If it doesn't exist as a value elsewhere, it states that that person doesn't have a grandfather.

Comment: your code is equivalent to this cleaned up version at the moment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MqsXMxPd ; the `findFather` method simply re-implements built-in dictionary lookups while using 2 unused variables and 3 useless assignments in the process.

Comment: anyway, so you want to find the grandfather then?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And if there isn't one, to simply state that that person doesn't have a grandfather.

Comment: Posted a solution; hopefully you'll be able to understand what's happening where and why; if not, ask.

Comment: Oh and... how on earth is the question title related to anything whatosever in the question itself?

Comment: I was thinking that if I could get some sort of count, then if the value is found, it could do key - 1 by going to the previous key and printing it.

Comment: dictionary elements aren't ordered, and even if they were, there would be no defined meaningful ordering in a database of person=>father pairs —I'm also not at all sure what's missing from my answer as you haven't responded to it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, you're trying to find the grandfather of a person in a database mapping people to their fathers:

```
def read_db(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return dict(pair.split(":")
                    for pair in line.strip().split(", ")
                    for line in f)


def grandfather(db, person):
    return db.get(db.get(person))  # same as db[db[person]] except returns None when no match found instead of error


def main():
    DB = read_db("names.dat")

    print "\n".join("father: %s son: %s" % pair for pair in DB)

    person = raw_input("Enter a son's name: ")
    print grandfather(DB, person)  # prints None if no father or no grandfather found


main()
```

As you can see, `DB` is the only needed variable in the entire program (`person` in `main` can also be inlined); in your question, your code contains a lot of noise that does absolutely nothing preventing you from understanding your code and making your question look very untidy. So try to clean everything up next time you ask a question on Stack Overflow. Also, check out the almighty [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)!

Comment: This helps out, and I do understand what is you have, but I am specifically told to only use a dictionary, so I don't believe I can use the database.

Comment: the "database" *is* a dictionary... "database" is just a variable name.